# Angular : How to exclude backslash and double quotes in my validator pattern

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I want to ensure that input fields doesn't contain backslash or Double Quotes characters

[image]  [image]
What is the pattern please ?

```
 reportForm = this.fb.group({
summary: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.pattern()]], 
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `{3,}` instead of the `+` you could also remove the `minLength` Validator, since it is then included into the pattern.

```js
var pattern = /^[^\\"]+$/;
console.log(pattern.exec('abc')); // 'abc' -> OK
console.log(pattern.exec('ab"c')); // null -> ERR
console.log(pattern.exec('\\abc')); // null -> ER
```

Comment: your code works in JS directly but not in Angular Validators.pattern(...) it doesn't recognize the backslashes